# Full Rails 5 routes with Ancestry Gem nested tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

I am using the [Ancestry Gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) in my Rails 5 app and all things look and act as they should and my database looks good.  I just can't figure out  out how to show the full url path after the first level following the model name.

**For Example**

I need `http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/29` to look like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/22/29` (I'll implement friendly ids after its working).  In the above example, `id:29` is a subpage of ancestry `id:22`

**Screenshot of Database**

[image]

**page.rb**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
...
private
...
def page_params
 params.require(:page).permit(:name, :content, :ancestry, :slug, :parent_id)
end
...
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.text "content"
  t.string "ancestry"
  t.string "slug"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["ancestry"], name: "index_pages_on_ancestry"
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
resources :pages
root to: 'pages#index'
...
```

**127.0.0.1:3000/rails/info/routes**

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url      
Path Match
stripe_event_path       /webhooks/stripe    
StripeEvent::Engine

new_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    
devise/sessions#new

user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    
devise/sessions#create

destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   
devise/sessions#destroy

new_user_password_path  GET /users/password/new(.:format)   
devise/passwords#new

edit_user_password_path GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  
devise/passwords#edit

user_password_path  PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   
devise/passwords#update

PUT /users/password(.:format)   
devise/passwords#update

POST    /users/password(.:format)   
devise/passwords#create

cancel_user_registration_path   GET /users/cancel(.:format) 
devise/registrations#cancel

new_user_registration_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    
devise/registrations#new

edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   
devise/registrations#edit

user_registration_path  PATCH   /users(.:format)    
devise/registrations#update

PUT /users(.:format)    
devise/registrations#update

DELETE  /users(.:format)    
devise/registrations#destroy

POST    /users(.:format)    
devise/registrations#create

users_path  GET /users(.:format)    
users#index

POST    /users(.:format)    
users#create

new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    
users#new

edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   
users#edit

user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    
users#show

PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    
users#update

PUT /users/:id(.:format)    
users#update

DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    
users#destroy

pages_path  GET /pages(.:format)    
pages#index

POST    /pages(.:format)    
pages#create

new_page_path   GET /pages/new(.:format)    
pages#new

edit_page_path  GET /pages/:id/edit(.:format)   
pages#edit

page_path   GET /pages/:id(.:format)    
pages#show

PATCH   /pages/:id(.:format)    
pages#update

PUT /pages/:id(.:format)    
pages#update

DELETE  /pages/:id(.:format)    
pages#destroy

root_path   GET /   
pages#index

Routes for StripeEvent::Engine
root_path   POST    /   
stripe_event/webhook#event
```

Comment: what does `rake routes` say?

Comment: @sean I updated my question with my routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Problem

You want to perform a `GET` request `/pages/:anchestry_id/:id` for action `pages#show`

### Solution

You need to add a special route at the top of your `routes.rb` file

```
get '/pages/:anchestry_id/:id' => 'pages#show', as: 'page'
```

You need to understand where you want to have that link, so from which pages in your app you want to call the action `pages#show`, because you will need to go to that controller action and in that action retrieve the 2 variables required for that link, which are `@anchestry` and `@page`

If you are doing this from the `pages#index`, then you will have many links and you will have to query all the `@ancestries` and `@pages` then loop them in the view to create many links

pages_controller.rb

```
def index
    @ancestries = Ancestry.all
    @pages = Page.all
end
```

Then you need to add a link in the pages

```
<%= link_to 'page', page_path(@ancestry, @page) %>
```

Or in the case of the `pages/index.html.erb`, which will use `@pages` and `@ancestries` do

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
     <%= link_to 'page', page_path(page.ancestry, page) %>
<% end %>
```

the problem is that as I see from your db, some entries have the ancestry as nil

```
31 About us Description of company [Null]
```

this will trigger a routes error, because you will be passing `page.ancestry = nil` and you can not have a route `/pages/null/31`

So I believe you need to put your thought back together and think about the design of your app architecture.

**Also why passing the `ancestry` in your route?**
All this does not make sense

Comment: Great answer.  As for passing the ancestry into my route,  I need to have SEO strong URL patterns.  If I leave off the ancestry or parent page, then an important piece of the url will be missing.  Does this make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: @StudioRooster sorry, I am not an expert in SEO. I don't know what you mean for `ancestry`, but the way to go with rails is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources using nested resources if there is a relationship between the `Ancestry` and the `Page` model